# Determine if wire in switch box is safe to re-purpose?

Tags: wiring, switch

I need to pull a neutral wire to my light switch for a smart switch.  It's presently switching an outlet that I don't need switched, and the other side of the outlet already has unswitched power.  My plan is to use a smart switch, which requires neutral, to control a different device wirelessly.

I can't feasibly run a new wire, because the wires aren't run through conduit.  Instead, my plan is to repurpose the switched wire to get neutral from the outlet.

The switch, which controls an outlet has two wires, one black and one red.  The switched outlet has a white neutral wire, plus the red and black wires that I assume run directly to the switch.

I've completely disconnected the red and black wires from the outlet and the switch.  The black wire is measuring 120V AC when measured against ground using the box as ground, both at the outlet and at the switch. Using my DMM, the red wire is measuring 24V AC with respect to the box/ground at both sides.  I assume this is a [ghost voltage](http://www.fluke.com/fluke/uses/comunidad/fluke-news-plus/articlecategories/electrical/dualimpedance) caused by induction from the charged black wire over to the floating red wire.

Our house is ~100 years old and this particular switch seems to be run using armored cable (note the paper wrap around each wire.)  There are literally only two wires in the switch box; no wire nuts.

If relevant, we do have some old knob and tube wiring active, but I'm pretty confident there's none on this circuit.

Is there some way I can determine with enough confidence that the red wire isn't connected elsewhere such that I can know it's safe to connect the red wire at the outlet to netural?

[image: Outlet]
[image: Switch box]

Comment: Are you sure it's AC and not conduit?

Comment: Also, are you sure there isn't another junction box between the two?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEeel There's clearly something in between feeding the black wire 120V; given that I'm getting 120V on it when both sides are connected.  Similarly, there's clearly something connected to the red wire in between.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I don't understand your first question.  Typo?

Comment: No, I'm asking because armored cable isn't made in red/black.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The AC acronym threw me off.  I'm using the term armored cable loosely here, meaning not run with conduit.  I just noticed it's not entirely visible in the photo, but each switch wire is individually wrapped in paper.  It's my understanding that there would never be paper-wrapped wires run through conduit.

Comment: Also, can you put a low-impedance tester from the red wire to ground? (Say a DMM on Low-Z mode, or an electrician's contact-type voltage tester.)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I can't now; I put everything back together since I am now confident that the red wire isn't a direct connection between the switch and the outlet.  I'd been hoping to repurpose the wire as a neutral feed to the switch.  

What might measuring the impedance between red and ground detect?

Comment: What the low-impedance tester detects is if the voltage is an actual wired connection or simply capacitive coupling to an unconnected wire.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel So are you suggesting that it's possible that the red wire is actually an uninterrupted connection between the switch and the outlet, and that the voltage is being produced by electromagnetic induction since it's run next to the hot wire?   And that measuring the impedance would tell us that?

Comment: Not measuring the impedance, measuring the *voltage* with an instrument that has a low impedance.

Comment: Also, once you unbutton it again, can you post better photos of the insides of both boxes?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel my cheap DMM doesn't have a low impedance mode; However, I bet you are spot on and that this is a ghost voltage from the disconnected wire running alongside the hot wire.  http://www.fluke.com/fluke/uses/comunidad/fluke-news-plus/articlecategories/electrical/dualimpedance

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Thanks for indirectly pointing out the ghost voltage problem.  I reworded the question, so please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet that the 40V measurement is likely a "[ghost voltage](http://www.fluke.com/fluke/uses/comunidad/fluke-news-plus/articlecategories/electrical/dualimpedance)," which is a misleading reading that can show up as a side effect of using a digital voltmeter on a dead wire.  The misleading measurement happens because there is capacitive coupling when you have an un-energized wire running next to an energized one.  The impedance of the voltmeter itself causes the high voltage to register, though the current it is capable of delivering would be miniscule. In this case, it would be from the switched wire running next to the hot wire.

To determine whether or not the voltage is actually present and being fed from a true voltage source, rather than being a misleading reading of an induced voltage from an adjacent wire, you need a low-impedance voltmeter.  Fluke makes several.

Given that this is the only time I am likely ever going to need this test, I'm not going to purchase a [dedicated low-impedance tester](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003WLLH2Y).  Instead of doing that I'm going to do a few brute-force tests.

We're going to start with the assumption that the red wire is likely connected to nothing other than the outlet.  Today, when the switch is closed, it sends connects the black wire to the red one and sends hot down the red wire.

As far as we know, no other devices are connected to this switch.  If we shut off the circuit breaker, connect both ends of the red wire to ground, then turn it back on, the circuit breaker shouldn't trip.  If this is the case, measure the current from the red wire to ground on each side, and from the red wire to neutral and hot.  There shouldn't be any current flowing into or out of a dead wire, period.

Obviously, this was done at my own risk.  Current to ground came up with .001 mA.  Tied the red wire to neutral at the outlet, connected the smart switch, and works like a charm.